# How can I specify a variable as the first argument in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I only started python recently and have never written any code before. I used a regular expression to match a string in the input file (which was successful) but I am really struggling to find a way to replace that string in the file with another using a regular expression.

```
with open( fileToSearch, "r+" ) as file:
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    string4=line
    result1 = re.search(r'(KNOWLEDGECENTER\/.*?\/)' + re.escape(taxonomy), string4)
    print (result1)
    result2 = re.sub(result1, r'(KNOWLEDGECENTER\/\t(\1)\/\)' + taxonomy, string4)
    print (result2)
    file.write(result2)
```

I expected that re.sub would replace the string in the result1 variable with the replacement string but instead, I am getting the following error:

raise TypeError, "first argument must be string or compiled pattern"
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

If I put the result1 variable in quotes in the re.sub statement, as shown below, I don't get an error but the input file doesn't get updated with the replacement string

```
result2 = re.sub('result1', r'(KNOWLEDGECENTER\/\t(\1)\/\)' +  
taxonomy, string4)
```

re.search code appears to work as print (result1) returns: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02A120E0> for each line in the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `re.sub` itself can perform a search, you don't need a separate call to `re.search`. In fact, you will lose the capture group in the regex for your call to `re.search` in the resulting match so the backreference in the replacement string in your call to `re.sub` won't be able to refer to anything. Combine to two calls and it will work (the below example code assumes that all you want to do is to add a tab after `KNOWLEDGECENTER/`:

```
for line in fileinput.input(fileToSearch):
    result = re.sub('(KNOWLEDGECENTER/)(.*?/' + re.escape(taxonomy) + ')', r'\1\t\2', line)
    file.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

[search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns an object ([MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)) with various attributes related to regex match, not a string or compiled pattern hence the error. Maybe what you want is `re.sub(results1.group(0), ...)`

(By the way, you have python 2.7 as keyword. If that's the version you are using consider upgrading to python 3 instead)